# change background of div based on page(index, about, contact etc.)

Tags: php, html, css

So I have a header.php file. here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
#header{background: url(images/bg-img.jpg); height:550px}
<style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="header">
```

Then I have my pages(index.php about.php contact.php) all which begin by closing the div in the header.php file.

```
<?php include('header.php');?>     


</div> <!-- end of "header" div -->
</div> <!-- end of "container" div -->
```

and the rest of the page follows ending with a footer at the bottom.

my question is how can I dynamically load a unique background color/image of the header based on the page im on?

would doing this be more basic with another language like react.js or something?

Comment: If you only have three files, where you use the header, and you want to have a different color for each. Why don't you just write the short code for the header in the three files each accordingly with the wanted color, instead of making a separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can go about doing this. You can either get the name of the page dynamically (for example by using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), or you can define a variable in each script that you use.

So your header would be..

```
<?php
$background = 'bg-img.jpg'; // Default background image 
                            // use this if $background is not set or does not have 
                            // a case in the switch below
if (isset($page)) {
    switch ($page) {
        case "contact":
            $background = 'bg-img-contact.jpg'; // Contact-page background
            break;
        case "about":
            $background = 'bg-img-about.jpg'; // About-page background
            break;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
#header{background: url(images/<?php echo $background; ?>); height:550px}
<!-- rest of header --->
```

Then you would assign the `$page` in each page, before including the header. (`include` is not a function and does not need parenthesis around it).

```
<?php 
$page = "contact";
include 'header.php';
?>     


</div> <!-- end of "header" div -->
</div> <!-- end of "container" div -->
```

Comment: Can you share the _$SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variation of it?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$page_bg_color = "#ff4500";
include(header.php);

etc.
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:<?php echo $page_bg_color; ?>">

<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="header">
```

Answer (score 0):

> would doing this be more basic with another language like react.js or
>   something?

If you plan on maintaining this application for a while, you might consider bringing in a framework. But I wouldn't consider bringing in a framework for *only* this. If you introduce a framework, you should plan on investing some time with it and leaning into its features. Most frameworks, in my experience, will approach template rendering in a wildly different way than you've outlined here.

> my question is how can I dynamically load a unique background
>   color/image of the header based on the page im on?

I'd approach it purely with CSS.

Whatever page you're on can load it's own CSS and specify a more specific selector, thus taking priority over the selector you've specified in header.php:

```
<style>
    div.row#header {
        background: /* whatever */ ;
    }
</style>
```

You could also add `!important` to ensure that this rule will have priority:

```
<style>
    #header {
        background: /* whatever */ !important;
    }
</style>
```

These CSS styles would go directly into your page specific code, or loaded in a separate CSS file that is exclusive to each page.

Some people might complain about having multiple `<style>` tags, but in my opinion adding multiple `<style>` tags is better than adding the mental overhead from a home-rolled PHP solution to put the CSS is the right place.